# How to set width of \suggestion and align its numbering when using xcookybooky for type setting recipes

Tags: alignment, books, xcookybooky

I like to know how to set width for 'suggestion' in xcookybooky for type setting recipes. The the command i used for setting widths for ingredients and preparation are as follows:

```
\setRecipeLengths{
    preparationwidth = 0.65\textwidth,
    ingredientswidth = 0.45\textwidth
}
```

Another issues i am facing is of numbering alignment. For each suggestion environment i use, the last number and its entry goes out of alignment. The following is the suggetion environment used (Also See entry 6 in figure), kindly suggest a solution for this too:

```
\suggestion[Variations]{
    \step Add \unit[1]{tsp} of balsamic or apple cider vinegar at the end
    \step Add \unit[\half]{Tbsp} of lemon juice at the end
    \step Dice a sweet apple (\textit{e.g.} honeycrisp) and add half way through roasting to potatoes.  Top with Parmesan
    \step Top with grated Parmesan or Asiago.
    \step Toss with \unit[\quarter]{c} tart dried fruit (\textit{e.g.} craisins) and feta at end.
}
```

The following is what a get after compilation:
[image]

The following is the full code used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcookybooky}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bookman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\let\half\textonehalf
\let\quarter\textonequarter
\newcommand\textfahrenheit{\textdegree F}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcelcius}{\ensuremath{^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\renewcommand*{\recipesection}[2][]
{%
    \subsection[#1]{#2}
}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]
{% no implementation to display the section name instead
}

\hbadness=10000 % Ignore underfull boxes
\setlength\parindent{20pt}
\setRecipeLengths{
    preparationwidth = 0.65\textwidth,
    ingredientswidth = 0.45\textwidth
}

\renewcommand{\step}
{%
    \stepcounter{step}%shouldn't be in the argument of lettrine
    \lettrine
    [%
    lines=2,
    lhang=0,          % space into margin, value between 0 and 1
    loversize=0.15,   % enlarges the height of the capital
    slope=0em,
    findent=1em,      % gap between capital and intended text
    nindent=0em       % shifts all intended lines, begining with the second line
    ]{\thestep}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}[preparationtime = {\unit[10]{min}}]{Sour Cream Dip}
    \introduction{%
        A guise under which to sneak a commoner into a fancy ball.  Adjust
        flavors to taste before moving to a clean bowl for presentation.
    }
    \ingredients{%
        \unit[1]{c}&Sour Cream\\
        \unit[2]{Tbsp}&Olive Oil (divided)\\
        \unit[0.5]{c}&Grated Parmesan\\
        \unit[1]{tsp}&Smoke Flavoring\\
        Spices:&Paprika, Salt, \& Pepper
    }
    \preparation{%
        \step Mix sour cream, \unit[1]{Tbsp} olive oil, Parmesan, and
        smoke flavoring in a bowl.  Season with salt and pepper to
        taste.  Move to clean bowl and sprinkle with paprika and drizzle
        remaining olive oil.
        
    }

    \suggestion[Variations]{
    \step Add \unit[1]{tsp} of balsamic or apple cider vinegar at the end
    \step Add \unit[\half]{Tbsp} of lemon juice at the end
    \step Dice a sweet apple (\textit{e.g.} honeycrisp) and add half way through roasting to potatoes.  Top with Parmesan
    \step Top with grated Parmesan or Asiago.
    \step Toss with \unit[\quarter]{c} tart dried fruit (\textit{e.g.} craisins) and feta at end.
}
\hint{%
\textbf{Enjoy this recipe and don't follow the variations to mess up !!}}

\end{recipe}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the 1st problem preparationwidth +ingredientswidth must be less than or equal to 1\textwidth (0.65\textwidth+0.45\textwidth=1.1\textwidth)
For the 2nd problem add \par to the last step (and feta at end.\par)

Comment: Thanks second problem is resolved.  For the first i need something like suggestionwidth = 0.6\textwidth

Comment: Not ideal, with minipage: \suggestion[Headline]{%
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
        blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
    \end{minipage}